# array access denied

Tags: java, arrays, jpanel

Ok. So I declare a 2D array up top like so:

```
private JPanel[][] panels = new JPanel[10][8];
```

Then I fill it like so:

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            JPanel temp = new JPanel();
            if(rand.nextInt(10)+1 > 8 && (j != 0 && i != 0)){
                temp.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                temp.setName("wall");                   
            }else{
                temp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                temp.setName("space");
            }
            c.gridx = j;
            c.gridy = i;
            boardCotent.add(temp,c);
            panels[j][i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Ok so then, I output it to make sure it populated right?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        System.out.println(j + ":" + i + " -> " + panels[j][i].getName());
    }
}
```

Here's a sample of the output from the above for loop:

```
2:2 -> wall
3:2 -> null
4:2 -> null
5:2 -> wall
```

So obviously, it worked...

Then in a switch, I'm trying to access it to see if it's a "wall" or a "space" and I get a null pointer exception... Does anyone see a flaw here I'm missing?

```
if(y > 0 && !panels[x][y-1].getName().matches("wall")){
    y--;
}
```

Comment: `panels[x][y-1]` is null when `y` is `3` and `x` is `3` or `4`.

Comment: I didn't paste it here. It was a switch on a private variable that indicated which direction a player is headed. Hence the y or x being incremented/decremented. I've tested the switch out every way from Sunday and it's fine. I isolated the problem to this array... I do have it fixed now and I'm struggling with refreshing my pane to actually "move" my player around my board... I'll post a question on that if I can't turn anything up in my research and the documentation. Thanks for the reply all! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2:2 -> wall
3:2 -> null
4:2 -> null
5:2 -> wall
```

First there is probleme with this part. Instead of `null` value you should have `space`.

```
if(y > 0 && !panels[x][y-1].getName().matches("wall"))
{
    y--;
}
```

Second, check `0 <= x < 10` and `0 <= y < 8` when you execute this code.

Comment: Right, sorry I pasted the wrong info from my output. It does say space and not null on the two middle ones.. sorry bout that.. I put that check in my code, good idea. It didn't fix the problem though. It started working after I stopped trying to put an icon on a JLabel into my panel... so I'm working on that issue now. Thanks for the input Cyril. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not mixing indices of both array dimensions?
Simply try the following to check:

```
int maxY = 10, maxX = 8;
private JPanel [][] panels = new JPanel[maxY][maxX];

for(int y = 0; y < maxY; y++)
  for(int x = 0; x < maxX; x++)
  {
     panels[y][x] = new JPanel();
     System.out.println("array[y=" + y + "][x=" + x + "] = " + panels[y][x]);
  }
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NPE with

```
if(y > 0 && !panels[x][y-1].getName().matches("wall")){ 
    y--; 
}
```

means you need do some null checking

```
if(y > 0 && panels[x][y-1] != null && !panels[x][y-1].getName().matches("wall")){
```